# Proof of Cantor's Intersection Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

I am going through metric spaces by Michael Searcoid. The text proves the Cantor's Intersection theorem as shown in the image below.

I understand the proof. However, just one thing, I am a little in doubt over is the use of specifying that $\mathcal F$ is a **nest** of non-empty subsets of $X$.

Where have we used the property of nested subsets as being absolutely necessary (**other than in forming the metric definition)** in this proof?

Thank you very much for your help in this regard.

**PS:** If the image does not seem to zoom, please drag it to a new tab in the same window and click zoom. Thanks again!

[image: Cantor's Intersection Theorem]
[image: Proof of the Cantor's Intersection Theorem]

Comment: From the proof, "...because either $A \subseteq S$ or $S \subseteq A$", where both $A, S$ belong to the family of subsets. This wouldn't be true unless the family was nested.

Comment: Where is says "Since $\mathcal F$ is a nest, $A\cap C$ is either $A$ or $C$", it seems to be using that assumption.  Without going into the proof too closely, let's see if we can show that the conclusion is false if we drop the assumption that it's a nest.  Just let $\mathcal F$ be the set of all bounded non-empty subsets of $\mathbb R^n$.  Then certainly $\displaystyle\bigcap_{A\in\mathcal F} \bar A= \varnothing \vphantom {\frac \int {\displaystyle\int}}$ and $\inf\{\operatorname{diam} A \mid A\in\mathcal F\}=0$. Can one then show that there is no point $z$ of the sort described? ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Thank you very much. Got it. I inspected more carefully and found logic in the way the author chose to give the proof.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the last paragraph of your proof it is clearly written there "let A$\in$F arbitrary. Since F is a nest...."

Basically neestedness needed to prove intersection non-empy and infimum of diameters is zero is needed to prove that intersection contains exactly one elememt.

Comment: Thanks. I inspected more carefully and found  out the reason why the author chose to give the proof in that manner.